# Simple JAX-RS with Tomcat - 404 Not Found (No web.xml)

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

**SERVICE**

```
    @Path("/rest")
    public class JustService {

        @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")
        @Path("sayhi")
        public String sayhi(){
            return "Hi";
        }
     }
```

**Application Config**

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

Tomcat Runs on port 8080 and heres the **Postman** request I'm sending : 
`localhost:8080/rest/sayhi` 
**response**

```
"status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
```

Here's the **POM.XML** :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**FIX** 
Anyone stuck on this problem here's the fix -> as @cassiomolin suggested
In your `ApplicationConfig` change the extended class from `Application` to -> `ResourceConfig`, and then add :

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig() extends ResourceConfig{
    // I also changed the name of class to JerseyConfig (this is optional of course )

     public JerseyConfig() {
         register(JustService.class);
     }
     //change JustService to your service class and add as many register's as service classes you have.
    // you can add @ApplicationPath annotation to this class if you need to
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and use only the `spring-boot-starter-jersey` dependency. Then annotate the `JustService` class with `@Component`:

```java
@Component
@Path("/rest")
public class JustService {
    ...
}
```

And finally add the following class to your application:

```java
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(JustService.class);
    }
}
```

For more details, refer to the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey).

Comment: HEY IT WORKED ! Thanks, but I'm confused, my ApplicationConfig.java doesn't really seem to do anything, I've set the `ApplicationPath("/jaxrs")` and also created your `JerseyConfig`, the url must be something like - `localhost:8080/jaxrs/rest/sayhi` , but it works only without `jaxrs` in url path. :/

Comment: @TornikeShelia Add the `@ApplicationPath` annotation to `JerseyConfig`. And remove your `ApplicationConfig` class.